# Migration between the different linux distributions?

Tags: package-management, configuration, migration

I am interested in installing Ubuntu as I have become familiar with it, and then in the future I would like to switch to Debian.

The issue is that I, personally, I like to configure the applications in a personalized way, adapt the desktop, toolbars and so on and not to lose time and make it practical to use.

I am not sure if in the /home all the configurations that the user makes on the system (including the packages installed) are saved and if it is compatible between the different Linux distributions, for example, Debian.

In addition to copying /home to migrate settings and personal documents, do you have to copy another file or folder so that is as similar as possible when you migrate to another distribution?

Is there a security risk when doing this?

Comment: Not everything is saved in `/home` , system-wide  config goes into `/etc`, specific applications may be storing config files in non-standard locations as in `/opt` where 3rd party apps often go.  As for Debian vs Ubuntu, there is overlap, but there's plenty of differences, some packages may need to be configured differently.  Security risk can exist if OS from which you're copying files was compromised. There's a lot of things to address.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Very interesting! Could you share some tips in a free time to keep the system as identical as possible when making the migration? Do you think there would be more people interested in doing this? A good reason may be, because the user wanted to learn how to use the system in VirtualBox and then the decision was made to use it as the main system.

Comment: I'm not an expert on migration, but I'll consider posting an answer with whatever I know.  As for system in VirtualBox and real system, it should be straightforward considering that it's the same OS.